# Android: custom shaped button

Tags: android, button

I'm looking the best way to create a group of four buttons.

[image]

Each button is an image. So, I think about just create a "big" square from four small images-buttons and then rotate them. 

The question is: how to rotate layout in xml? Is it possible?

Is there any better way to create such group of buttons?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a single ImageButton, then use trigonometry to work out where the user has clicked on the circle, using data from an onClick() event and the centre of the button. This question may help:
[Get the co-ordinates of a touch event on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939332/get-the-co-ordinates-of-a-touch-event-on-android)

Comment: thank you! nice approach, will try it.
the only issue I see - different screens...

Comment: Different screens shouldn't matter if you always know the co-ordinates of the centre of the button, and the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 5):

The ultimate answer is to use a pathshape button. Then it handles everything for you.

Create the paths with [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) the shapes with [Shape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html) and the composite pathshape with 
[Pathshape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html).

That way you can do it even in XML.
And there's a variety of arc path methods. 
Check it out!