# Ovelay image over loaded image in the touched position

Tags: android, android-overlay

I need to add a picture over a touched position in an image or directly on camera preview.

How could get the touch coordinates and set the image in the touched area?

And If I want to move the added images?

What is the right way to code this stuff? Is there some sample or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

event.getX() and event.getY() should give you the coordinates.

Here is a more detailed answer on getting the coordinates. [Get the co-ordinates of a touch event on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939332/get-the-co-ordinates-of-a-touch-event-on-android)