# How to take first touch co-ordinates

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How to take first touch coordinates and make it constant.
I wanna click something on screen then draw a permanent on first touch and then want to move another circle within the the permanent circle one

hers the code am trying :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
private float x;
private float y;
static float lasttouchx;
static float lasttouchy;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyCustomPanel view = new MyCustomPanel(this);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    addContentView(view, params);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

private class MyCustomPanel extends View {


    public MyCustomPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);




        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText(" X : " + (int) x + " Y : " + (int) y, canvas.getWidth() - 500, 200, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        if((x<=1000&& x>=18)&&(y<=1380&&y>=348)){
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 100, paint);


            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            canvas.drawCircle(lasttouchx, lasttouchy, 500, paint);


        }
        else{}




    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
   switch (action){
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           lasttouchx = event.getX();
           lasttouchy = event.getY();
           return false;





    }


    v.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and then call `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to get the coordinate positions of where the user touched.

then store value to some variable.

now use these values you want and try replacing to another.

Check stack answer [to get touch screen information answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068007/android-how-do-i-get-raw-touch-screen-information)